# In the SplitView when custom view is added, scrollers are not coming and complete view is not visible

Tags: swift, cocoa, nssplitview

I have a split view and to one of the view I am adding a custom view.
The custom view is larger in size. So ideally scrollers should come.

Could any one let me know why scrollers are not coming. The custom view is shown as the size of the split view only.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you add scrollers or a scroll view?

Comment: Yes, the size mist=match was there, so modified the content view and now issue is resolved.